# Microsoft Ergonomic Keyboards With Card Readers?

Tags: physical-security

When I started working at my current job I developed tendinitis in my wrists.  Luckily that cleared up when I started using a Microsoft ergonomic keyboard.  The problem is that where I work is moving to more security.  We will need to stick a card into a slot to log into our PCs.  They bought a bunch of new keyboards with these slots built in.   All regular keyboards.

Is there something like the Microsoft Ergonomic keyboard that comes with such a card slot?

Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry but this is a shopping question and therefore off-topic on any [SE] site. Please see our [FAQ].

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing stopping you from having two keyboards on a system. Plug in the keyboard with the log on device, put it somewhere where it dosen't mess with your workflow, and type on the MS ergonomic. Alternatively, since you're looking at alternatives, see if there's a standalone cardreader.

Chances are either would be simpler than finding the perfect ergo keyboard *with* a card slot compatible with what you are using.

Comment: Journeyman Geek, thanks for taking the time to answer.  I found your comment to be very helpful.  I am grateful that the moderation staff let me see your useful answer despite their high standards.